# I have a question about Http Transfer-Encoding and Content-Encoding

Tags: http, networking, rfc

There is a descrbies as below in rfc7230:
"Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked
indicates that the payload body has been compressed using the gzip coding and then chunked using the chunked coding while forming themessage body"

My question is "Transfer-Encoding" is not attribution of message, it only refers to how to transport messgae, But Content-Encoding is the attribution of message, Why Transfer-Encoding has a value called gzip???, is not the Content-Encoding's "work"????